# Force Visual Studio (2022) to run Azure Functions on WSL

Tags: linux, visual-studio, azure-functions, visual-studio-2022

Is there a way to force Visual Studio 2022 to debug an Azure Function locally using WSL? (The option does not seem to be there).

My guess would be this is because Functions are platform agnostic. IF that is the case, and it does not matter whether it's linux or azure, that's fine. But I would still like to be able to do so, even if to see if my env variables work (__ vs : ).

So is there a way to debug in visual studio, and have it assume that the OS the function is running on is linux?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

- On my research, I found we can do the Azure Functions debugging locally using VS Code with WSL2 where I found an [dev article](https://dev.to/videlalvaro/azure-functions-with-wsl2-and-visual-studio-code-56c1) given by @*AlvaroVidela* and a GitHub Repo [Article](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-core-tools/issues/941) for the steps to work with WSL on Azure Functions locally.
- I believe that if there is an option to use in VS Code IDE for working on Azure Functions locally then there will be an option definitely to work in Visual Studio 2022 IDE because as I can there is an update in this [MS Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/debug-dotnet-core-in-wsl-2?view=vs-2022) of debugging the .NET Applications in WSL in Linux without leaving the Visual Studio.